# Azure Mobile Services Component not found in Xamarin Component Store

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm working with Xamarin plugin in Visual Studio 2013.

I have an iOS app and I want to add the Azure Mobile Services client component to that app. But when I click "Get more components" and search for the component in the store, it is not found.

I tried doing the same from the Xamarin Studio on my mac and the component is there.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**
The component is now available in the component store for unified api projects. It became available 1 day after I asked my question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to add it to an iOS Classic project on the Mac with Xamarin Studio but using an iOS Unified project on Windows with Visual Studio.

Looking at the Xamarin Component Store the [Azure Mobile Services client](https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services) is currently only available for iOS Classic projects. You can see that by the tags. It has an **ios** tag but not an **ios-unified** tag.

Xamarin Studio will not show the component when you click **Get more components** if it is incompatible with the current project.

Comment: Seems like [support for unified API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/pull/545) has just been added to the client. Maybe it is not yet updated in the store.

Comment: And now also available in the store :-)